# Spring Batch - Unmarshall XML file to Json - Dynamic XML

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jaxb2

I'm doing a job that process a lot off xml files (dynamic), but I can't define the specific java object to @XmlRootElement. I think that i need to transform xml fragments to Map object.

For exemple: I don't know the structure of files, it is dynamic. I have two xml files and i try to execute only one job that process both files.

File 1 -

```
<Pessoa>
  <campos>
      <campo>
        <nome>Carlos</nome>
        <sobrenome>Silva</sobrenome>
      </campo>
      <campo>
        <nome>Carlos</nome>
        <sobrenome>Silva</sobrenome>
      </campo>
  </campos>
</Pessoa>
```

File 2 -

```
<Parent>
  <childs>
    <child>Lala</campo>
    <child>Lala</campo>
  </childs>     
</Parent>
```

The ItemReader and ItemProcessor have to execute both files. The files are dynamic and i can't inform the classes to be bound.
For example: My reader that extends StaxEventItemReader

```
    Jaxb2Marshaller unmarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    // It is possible? The Map.class hasn't @XmlRootElement declaration
    //unmarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(Map.class);
    setUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
    setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[] {"Pessoa", "Parent"});
```

Using spring batch to process this files are possible, according my requirements?

Thanks!

Comment: If there no class structure to use why don't you go directly from xml to json? You still don't have a class to generate the json if I understand this correctly

Comment: You can use Jsoup to put the xml into memory then use a JsonBuilder to create the son file

Comment: In this case I have to transform the xml file in json and process in spring batch. I think that this process will be expensive.

Comment: Spring batch is for jobs. The job is up to you. I was wondering if reading the xml file into jsoup then a simple dom processing into json will be more efficient. Without a class structure you are asking jaxb to create a dom. So why use jaxb?

Comment: Jaxb is a broker between class and file. If there is no class, why the overhead?

Comment: I was using spring batch to process my xml file and transform my data into some informations that are save at database. I told about transform xml file into json file and than collect the data that i need it is a overhead. I have xml files  bigger than 400Mb. Sorry if I'm not be clear.

Comment: Regardless of how you transform, there is no class structure jaxb will drag you down

Comment: Anyways, you can ignore my thoughts. I am off for a while

Answer (score 0):

Spring batch is for jobs. You would need to code the job still. The way you are describing the process, jaxb (which is a broker between class and file) is not needed because there is no class. It will start costing over a big enough batch job. I would by bypass jaxb,load the *.xml into memory with jsoup then transform into son with a json builder